# Set delegate of UIGestureRecorgniser to parent

Tags: swift, inheritance, uiview

I have a custom class that inherits from a UIView. In this class I add a gesture recogniser to it as so

```
//CustomParentView.swift 

class CustomParentView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupGestureRecognizer()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setupGestureRecognizer() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomParentView.viewTapped(sender:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func viewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("View tapped")
    }
}
```

Then I have another class that inherits from CustomParentView, and I will ultimately have a few UIViews that inherit from it, but the delegate for the gesture recogniser isn't set as the CustomParentView, it's set as the view that inherits it. This would mean I would need to move the `viewTapped` function into the subclass of each of the CustomParentView and repeat this function in every class.

So my question is how do I set the delegate for the gesture recogniser to be the CustomParentView and for it to stay the CustomParentView

Comment: Well as soon as you create child's instance, all member from its parent class becomes child's member. Like `backgroundColor` is `UIView` member, but you can set it in `UIImageView`, `UITableView` and all. It will behave as child's `backgroundColor`. So what you want to do ?

Comment: Dismiss the parent in parent class. Its child automatically dismiss.

Comment: I don't know what exactly `dismiss` means but try this line in `viewTapped()` function `self.removeFromSuperview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I have another class that inherits from CustomParentView, and I
>   will ultimately have a few UIViews that inherit from it, but the
>   delegate for the gesture recogniser isn't set as the CustomParentView,
>   it's set as the view that inherits it.

It doesn't matter which class you assign as the gesture recognizer delegate, it just has to implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.  Any subclass of `CustomParentView` will implement this protocol because the base class does.

> This would mean I would need to move the viewTapped function into the subclass of each of the CustomParentView and repeat this function in every class.

No you don't.  That isn't how object oriented programming and inheritance work.  All subclasses of `CustomParentView` will have the `viewTapped` method.

> So my question is how do I set the delegate for the gesture recogniser
>   to be the CustomParentView and for it to stay the CustomParentView

What you have works.  Did you try it?

You should also call `setupGestureRecognizer` from the other `init` so that it works with views created in the Storyboard:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupGestureRecognizer()
}
```